# Python - trying to capture the middle of a line, regex or split

Tags: python, regex, split

I have a text file with some names and emails and other stuff. I want to capture email addresses.

I don't know whether this is a split or regex problem.

Here are some sample lines:

```
[name]bill billy [email]bill.billy@hotmail.com [dob]01.01.81
[name]mark hilly [email]mark.hilly@hotmail.com [dob]02.11.80
[name]gill silly [email]gill.silly@hotmail.com [dob]03.12.79
```

I want to be able to do a loop that prints all the email addresses.

Thanks.

Comment: Is getting the emails the only thing you will ever want to do, or is it conceivable you might ever want to do more with the info later? If it's the latter, I think you definitely want Blender's answer. Anything that relies on plain `split` to split the fields (like most of the answers here) will never work for `name`; anything that relies on `split`ting around `]` will probably be more complicated than a regex (although I'd love to be proven wrong).

Comment: I think I may want to use the name later to make a mail more specific

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a regex:

```
import re

data = '''[name]bill billy [email]bill.billy@hotmail.com [dob]01.01.81
[name]mark hilly [email]mark.hilly@hotmail.com [dob]02.11.80
[name]gill silly [email]gill.silly@hotmail.com [dob]03.12.79'''

group_matcher = re.compile(r'\[(.*?)\]([^\[]+)')

for line in data.split('\n'):
    o = dict(group_matcher.findall(line))
    print o['email']
```

- `\[` is literally `[`.
- `(.*?)` is a non-greedy capturing group. It "expands" to capture the text.
- `\]` is literally `]`
- `(` is the beginning of a capturing group.
- `[^\[]` matches anything but a `[`.
- `+` repeats the last pattern any number of times.
- `)` closes the capturing group.

Comment: is there some website that easily describes the workings of (r'\[(.*?)\]([^\[]+)')  I'd like to understand it instead of just nicking it. But this is good!

Comment: @gjels: Not that I know of. See my edit for a brief explanation.

Comment: @gjels: Python has a [HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) in its docs, but it may not be the most beginner-friendly tutorial; try googling for others. Also get a regex explorer program (there are a zillion of them for each platform, plus a bunch of online ones), which will help you play around with things. Just make sure you learn Python syntax—perl/PCRE is close enough, but grep, emacs, etc. are very different.

Comment: I know this is late, but https://regex101.com/ gives a good explanation and allows you to test your regex.

Answer (score 3):

```
for line in lines:
   print line.split("]")[2].split(" ")[0]
```

Comment: @karthikr: I think you're forgetting that `'[name'` will be the first value in the split.

Comment: @abarnert He had a different answer earlier, and my comment was for that

Answer (score 1):

You can pass substrings to `split`, not just single characters, so:

```
email = line.partition('[email]')[-1].partition('[')[0].rstrip()
```

This has an advantage over the simple `split` solutions that it will work on fields that can have spaces in the value, on lines that have things in a different order (even if they have `[email]` as the last field), etc.

To generalize it:

```
def get_field(line, field):
    return line.partition('[{}]'.format(field)][-1].partition('[')[0].rstrip()
```

However, I think it's still more complicated than the regex solution. Plus, it can only search for exactly one field at a time, instead of all fields at once (without making it even more complicated). To get two fields, you'll end up parsing each line twice, like this:

```
for line in data.splitlines():
    print '''{} "babysat" Dan O'Brien on {}'''.format(get_field(line, 'name'), 
                                                      get_field(line, 'dob'))
```

(I may have misinterpreted the [DOB](https://twitter.com/DOB_INC) field, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

You can split by space and then search for the element that starts with `[email]`:

```
line = '[name]bill billy [email]bill.billy@hotmail.com [dob]01.01.81'
items = line.split()
for item in items:
    if item.startswith('[email]'):
        print item.replace('[email]', '', 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

say you have a file with lines.

```
import re

f = open("logfile", "r")
data = f.read()

for line in data.split("\n"):
    match=re.search("email\](?P<id>.*)\[dob", line)
    if match:
             # either store or print the emails as you like
             print match.group('id').strip(), "\n"
```

Thats all (try it, for python 3 n above remember print is a function make those changes ) !

The output from your sample data:

```
bill.billy@hotmail.com  

mark.hilly@hotmail.com  

gill.silly@hotmail.com  

>>>
```

Comment: If you're just matching against fixed strings like this, there's no real advantage to using a regex. Compare this with Blender's answer, which can get you all of the fields' names and values, instead of just whichever one you've hardcoded, and is much more robust (e.g., reorder the columns so `email` comes after `dob` instead of before).

Comment: i thought its a specific problem to solve not a generic problem. Generalizing extends the "scope" and robustness is all about "accomodating as per the scope".

Comment: If you just want to solve the specific problem, matching against fixed text strings, regex doesn't add anything on top of simple split, it just makes it slower and less readable for no reason. Compare to JaniSOF's solution, for example.